# Centered-fixed-width-div with fluid divs on left and right?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress site.
I have these decorative titles that are constructed like this:
*(the following is not the real html structure, it is just as example purpose)*

```
<div class="decoration-left"> <div class="title"> <div class="decoration-right">
```

.title has a h1 title inside. 
.decoration-left, and .decoration-right, are empty divs, with a decorative background. 
I need the title to be centered all the time.

I first tried to give all the three divs a 33.3% width, which worked nice on big screens, but as i reduce the window the title breaks into two lines, and it looks ugly. I need the title to have a constant width therefore. I dont want the text to be smaller.

Right now, i have the .title div with "width:auto" which works fine. however i need the left and right decorative divs to take each one, half of the remaining space in a responsive/fluid way.

attaching picture for better understunding.!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is: put your DECORATIVE divs inside the TITLE div, and your TITLE div inside a WRAP div. Make the TITLE div with 'position: relative; display:inline-block; background:#fff;' the DECORATIVE ones with 'position:absolute; left:-50px;' and 'position:absolute; right:-50px;', and the WRAP with 'text-align:center; background:url(LINE IMAGE LINK) center repeat-x;'.

I know it's hard to understand, but I am mostly sure it will work that way. I'll try making it look better by coding some of it:

HTML:

```
<div class="title-warpper">
 <div class="title">
  <div class="decoration-left"></div>
  <span>YOUR TITLE HERE</span>
  <div class="decoration-right"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.title-wrapper {
 background:url(LINE IMAGE LINK) center repeat-x;
 text-align: center;
}
div.title {
 position:relative;
 background:#fff;
 display:inline-block;
}
div.decoration-right{
 position:absolute;
 right:-25px;
 background:url(DECORATION BG LINK);
 width:25px;
 height:25px;
}
div.decoration-left{
 position:absolute;
 left:-25px;
 background:url(DECORATION BG LINK);
 width:25px;
 height:25px;
}
```

I set the decoration divs for 25px, but use what you need. Just remember to adjust them and the left and right properties to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind the title overlapping the decorative divs on some screen sizes then you can absolute position the decorative divs with

```
position:absolute;
left:0px; (OR right:0px;)
```

give them whatever width and height you like.